# Reading 2-D array from a file

Tags: java

I have a 2-D int array in file 'array.txt'. I am trying to read all the elements in the file in a two dimensional array. I am having problem in copying. It shows all the elements having value '0' after copying instead their original value. Please help me.
My code is :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class appMainNineSix {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws java.io.FileNotFoundException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner (new File("src/array.txt"));
        int m = 3;
        int n = 5;
        int[][] a = new int [m][n];
        while (input.next()!=null){
            for (int i=0;i<m;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
                    a[i][j]= input.nextInt();
            }   

        }
        //print the input matrix
        System.out.println("The input sorted matrix is : ");
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                System.out.println(a[i][j]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the file itself?

Comment: I tried ur code it prints the values of the array,but it throws an exception if u reach the end of the file!

Answer (score 9):

`while (input.next()!=null)`

This will consume something from the scanner input stream. Instead, try using `while (input.hasNextInt())`

Depending on how robust you want your code to be, you should also check inside the for loop that something is available to be read.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (new File("src/array.txt"));
// pre-read in the number of rows/columns
int rows = 0;
int columns = 0;
while(input.hasNextLine())
{
    ++rows;
    Scanner colReader = new Scanner(input.nextLine());
    while(colReader.hasNextInt())
    {
        ++columns;
    }
}
int[][] a = new int[rows][columns];

input.close();

// read in the data
input = new Scanner(new File("src/array.txt"));
for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
    {
        if(input.hasNextInt())
        {
            a[i][j] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative using ArrayLists (no pre-reading required):

```
// read in the data
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("src/array.txt"));
while(input.hasNextLine())
{
    Scanner colReader = new Scanner(input.nextLine());
    ArrayList col = new ArrayList();
    while(colReader.hasNextInt())
    {
        col.add(colReader.nextInt());
    }
    a.add(col);
}
```

Comment: That won't be sufficient given that `input.nextInt()` is called `m x n` times.

Comment: This allows you to know the size of the array before you read it in because arrays in Java are fixed-sized (i.e. you can't "extend" them). You could use an ArrayList of ArrayLists to accomplish this with only opening the file once (or implement an ArrayList-like structure yourself, though this is generally not recommended), or you could create a large enough array that whatever you read in will fit. I generally like the exact fit arrays or ArrayLists solutions.

Comment: If you don't know the size before hand use an ArrayList.

Comment: Then use ArrayList, if the other method forces you to read the file twice. I see no reason to use a fixedsize array in this case, to be honest. Frankly, I don't see why you would want to reimplement ArrayList either...

Comment: Added an addendum for code using an ArrayList of ArrayLists. No pre-reading is required. Personally, I've found that both methods are useful to know, though you're right that using an ArrayList is easier and less error-prone. There is only one reason I would implement my own ArrayList: it was for a class assignment. Otherwise, I would recommend just using Java's ArrayList class or do a pre-read to determine what size we need to read in (as stated above).

Comment: I tested this code on Ubuntu 14.04. It does not work since the while-loop to compute columnNumber will run forever.

Comment: One line is missing. colReader.nextInt();

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when u reach the end of the file it throughs an exception that no usch element exist.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub         
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("array.txt"));
        int m = 3;
        int n = 5;
        int[][] a = new int[m][n];
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                   try{//    System.out.println("number is ");
                    a[i][j] = input.nextInt();
                      System.out.println("number is "+ a[i][j]);
                    }
                   catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
                       // e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }         //print the input matrix
            System.out.println("The input sorted matrix is : ");
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    System.out.println(a[i][j]);

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I knew that making catch without processing the exception but it temporary works.
Please be aware I put the file outside the source folder.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem may be that you've got that pair of nested loops to read the numbers stuck *inside* that while loop.  Why would you want to **re-read** the array values after you've read them once? And note that if there's *anything* in the file after the last number, then you'll fill the array in with whatever `.nextInt()` returns after end-of-file has been reached!

*edit* — well `.nextInt()` should throw an exception I guess when input runs out, so that may not be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Start simple...

change:

```
for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
    a[i][j]= input.nextInt();
```

to:

```
for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    int value;

    value = input.nextInt();
    a[i][j] = value;
    System.out.println("value[" + i + "][" + j + " = " + value);
}
```

And make sure that the values are read in.

Also, you should not call next without first calling (and checking) hasNext (or nextInt/hasNextInt).

Comment: ’int value = input.nextInt();’ why not declare and assign in one go? Sorry just one of my pet peeves.

Comment: because I want things to be consistent, and since I cannot always declare and assign I never declare and assign.

Answer (score -1):

You can try Using Guava ,

```
public class MatrixFile {
    private final int[][] matrix;

    public MatrixFile(String filepath) {
        // since we don't know how many rows there is going to be, we will
        // create a list to hold dynamic arrays instead
        List<int[]> dynamicMatrix = Lists.newArrayList();

        try {
            // use Guava to read file from resources folder
            String content = Resources.toString(
                Resources.getResource(filepath),
                Charsets.UTF_8
            );

            Arrays.stream(content.split("\n"))
                .forEach(line -> {
                    dynamicMatrix.add(
                        Arrays.stream(line.split(" "))
                            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                            .toArray()
                    );
                });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // in case of error, always log error!
            System.err.println("MatrixFile has trouble reading file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        matrix = dynamicMatrix.stream().toArray(int[][]::new);
    }
```