# One-line Java scanner to read a matrix from a file

Tags: java, arrays, string, int, java.util.scanner

I have been using this; A kind of one-liner:

```
public static String[] ReadFileToStringArray(String ReadThisFile) throws FileNotFoundException{
    return (new Scanner( new File(ReadThisFile) ).useDelimiter("\\A").next()).split("[\\r\\n]+");
}
```

To read a file with this type of contents(i.e. with string tokens):

> abcd
>   abbd
>   dbcd

But, now my file contents are something like this:

> 1 2 3 4
>   1 2 2 4
>   1 5 3 7
>   1 7 3 8

I want these values to be read as integer.

I have seen these [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646392/convert-string-to-int-array-in-java), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185683/read-txt-file-into-2d-array) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769976/reading-2-d-array-from-a-file) questions but they do not answer to my question.

I have tried the following but failed:

```
public static int[][] ReadFileToMatrix(String ReadThisFile) throws FileNotFoundException{
    return (new Scanner( new File(ReadThisFile) ).useDelimiter("\\A").nextInt()).split("[\\r\\n]+");
}
```

**Error message:** *Cannot invoke `split(String)` on the primitive type `int`.* I understand the message and know it's horribly wrong :)

Can anybody suggest the right way to achieve this.

P.S. With all due respect, "NO" to solutions with loops.

Comment: Its pretty easy to read the numbers as `int`s and store them in 1D array. But i cannot think of a way to convert the 1D array in 2D without a loop. Or at least recursion..

Comment: According to Java conventions, variables (`readThisFile`) and method names (`readFileToMatrix`) are starting with lowercase letters.

Comment: You can google for "Java Naming Conventions", but here's a brief: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an over complication of using classes when a basic `BufferedReader` with `Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[n]);` will do.

Comment: Could you kindly write the complete line? how will it go after `return`?

Comment: Not in one line. Why do you need it on one line?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 7 or higher you can use something like this. I cannot think of a way to do it in one line without a loop. Just put this into a methode and call it.

```
//Read full file content in lines
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

int NR_OF_COLUMNS = 4;
int NR_OF_ROWS = lines.size();

int[][] result = new int[NR_OF_ROWS][NR_OF_COLUMNS];

for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NR_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++)
{
    String[] tokens = lines.get(rowIndex).split("\\s+");  //split every line
    for(int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < NR_OF_COLUMNS; columnIndex++)
        result[rowIndex][columnIndex] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[columnIndex]);   //convert every token to an integer
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8, you can use Lambdas:

```
public static int[][] readFileToMatrix(String readThisFile) throws FileNotFoundException{
    return Arrays.stream((new Scanner( new File(readThisFile) ).useDelimiter("\\A").nextInt()).split("[\\r\\n]+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
}
```

Otherwise you cannot do it without a loop. You have a `String[]` array, and you want to call `Integer.parseInt()` for each element, one by one.

Comment: Looks good, could you please add the detail of how it will map and then it will be returned back as an `int` 2D array.